# How to distinguish devmgmt's Disable and Uninstall from within my Windows driver code?

Tags: windows, driver, kmdf, wdm

I'm studying Microsoft Toaster sample code from WDK7, and I find a subtle problem.

Now trying the compiled drivers(WDM busenum and WDM featured1) on Windows 7.

As guided by README, `enum -p 1` adds a toaster device, then, I open device manager(devmgmt), find the device, **Uninstall** it.

[image: Uninstall toaster device from devmgmt.msc]

<strike>This will destroy the toaster devnode(I believe);</strike> we can see that *ToasterDevice01* node now disappears from Device Manager. `!devnode 0 1` shows that the toaster devnode still exists, with State=DeviceNodeUninitialized (0x301), Previous State=DeviceNodeRemoved (0x312).

Then, I execute `enum -p 1` trying to add the device again. But I got error 0x57(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

[image: enum -p 1 , got 0x57 error]

I debug the source code and identify the reason: `buspdo.c` does not distinguish between devmgmt's Disable and Uninstall operation. His code logic is:

- If toaster gets surprise-removed(`enum -u 1`), it calls `Bus_DestroyPdo()` which is correct behavior.
- If toaster gets Disabled from devmgmt, it does **not** call `Bus_DestroyPdo()`, which is also correct.

**The problem is**, when an end-user executes Uninstall from devmgmt, it follows the Disable path. Something bad now happens: Windows removes the toaster devnode, but toaster bus driver does not destroy the corresponding PDO, so, when next time user execute `enum -p 1`, the toaster bus driver `Bus_PlugInDevice()` blames that the toaster device with SerialNo==1 already exists and hence fail the user request.

[image]

BTW: Toaster's KMDF version exhibits similar problem(only static-enumeration version tried today)

Now my question is clear: How can I distinguish from Disable and Uninstall, shall I do it in bus driver or child device driver? Answer for KMDF version is also welcome.

Comment: Is the devnode really destroyed? I think it still may exist since the PDO exists (the PDO contains a reference to coresponding devnode). Does the sample behave the same way when you disable and then enable the the device via Device Manager.

Comment: Please tell me a way(like some stock utility) that is able to check whether a devnode exists, thank you.

Comment: I don't know about any tool able to do this. You can use my tool (https://github.com/MartinDrab/VrtuleTree/releases) to check whether the PDO is present after the uninstall (https://github.com/MartinDrab/VrtuleTree/releases - File -> Create snapshot and look for the \Driver\<toasterbusname>). The kernel seems to delete the devnode structure when deleting the PDO.

Comment: Thank you. I checked with your tool and DevTreeView from OSR; they both show the PDO for toaster child still exists, and I find out WinDBG `!devnode 0 1` shows that the devnode  still exists too. So, I have to set aside this problem and wait for a chance to solve it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can make a conclusion. Our client driver can NOT distinguish between Disable and Uninstall from Device Manager. This is Microsoft's design.

To make the distinguishment, we need the help from application layer. Provide a CoInstaller for the child device, and, when the CoInstaller gets DIF_REMOVE notification(this results from devmgmt doing Uninstall), send an custom IOCTL(e.g. IOCTL_UNPLUG_MY_CHILD) to the kernel driver so that kernel driver unplug corresponding child.